# Mongodb dynamic project in aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have my collection of structure

```
{ 
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4,
  e: 5,
  allowed: ['a', 'b']
}
```

In this collection, allowed array stores fields name to be fetched. It is set by the user preference which he wants to fetch and can change those selected fields and is updated in allowed array.

I want to fetch using MongoDB aggregate and project in some way that allowed array will be used
without manually listing all the fields in $project

`{ $project: { a: 1, b: 1 } }`

I have one solution like using below project in aggregate

```
  db.getCollection("dummy").aggregate([
      { $match: {} },
      {
        $project: {
          a: {
            $cond: {
              if: { $in: ["a", "$allowed"] },
              then: "$a",
              else: "$$REMOVE",
            },
          },
          b: {
            $cond: {
              if: { $in: ["b", "$allowed"] },
              then: "$b",
              else: "$$REMOVE",
            },
          },
        },
      },
    ]);
```

but this also requires listing all fields. I am looking for an alternate solution that projects fields in the allowed array without listing all fields manually in $project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you do not know what are  the fields in your documents, You have to convert them to `k`-`v` pair using [**`$objectToArray`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray) then use [**`$filter`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to filter out the fields which are not in `$allowed` array. FInally use [**`$arrayToObject`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) to get initial shape.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $replaceRoot: {
    newRoot: {
      $arrayToObject: {
        $filter: {
          input: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" },
          cond: { $in: ["$$this.k", "$allowed"] }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/P-130By-HxA)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response. It's working. I have learned something new today.